# spring integration jdbc init error

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

error info:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/spring/applicationContext-integration.xml]`

I have added xmlns and xsi:schemaLocation to the header of configuration file, it didn't show any error, but why excepiton occured when project startup?

anybody helps me...

Answer (score 2):

It's interest, what was the problem to use search? At least on the StackOverflow

Your issue is about that **spring-integration-jdbc.jar** isn't presented in the CLASSPATH

Cheers